# Sandisk Clip support plus player not recognized

Tags: usb, mount, mp3

I bought an brand new MP3 player en XUbuntu 18.04 and Xubuntu 20.04 does not mount. When I plugged in the player. Only when I plugged in before to start the computer/laptop it appears on the desktop. The older version I had, contains a MSC modus, this new one not.SanDisk does not response my question about plug and play.
MTP tools is installed but makes no difference. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: MTP/PTP tools are applicable to Android devices (starting on version 4 something, I think), not to mass storage devices.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl. --follow` as you connect the device

Comment: command sudo journalctl. --follow not found